# HttpClient not working on android

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I'm making Xamarin.Forms app which should get JSON from api and then allow to display it. My code so far:

```
    public async void jsonDownload()
    {
        connect();
        await downloadData();


    }
    public void connect()
    {
        client = new HttpClient();
        client.MaxResponseContentBufferSize = 256000;
    }
    public async Task<List<Jsonclass>> downloadData()
    {

        String url = "https://my-json-server.typicode.com/kgbzoma/TestJsonFile/all";
        var uri = new Uri(string.Format(url, string.Empty));
        try
        {

            var response = await client.GetAsync(uri).ConfigureAwait(false);
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode(); //NEVER GET HERE

            var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ConfigureAwait(false); 
            List = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Jsonclass>>(content);

        }catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(@"     Error {0}", ex.Message);
        }
        return List;
    }
```

Problem is that code don't even go to response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode(); so my list of objects is empty. On UWP version it's working without any problems.
Here i'm gettin exception: System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException with message An error occurred while sending the request.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> SecureChannelFailure (The authentication or decryption has failed.)

or

> System.Net.WebException: Error: TrustFailure

or

> Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.TlsException: Invalid certificate received from server.

By *default*, Xamarin.Android uses the older Mono Managed HttpClient handler that does not support TLS 1.2.

Open your `Xamarin.Android` project settings, goto `Build` / `Android Build` / `General` and use the `AndroidClientHandler`.

[image]

This will add the following MSBuild properties directly to your `.csproj`

```
<AndroidHttpClientHandlerType>Xamarin.Android.Net.AndroidClientHandler</AndroidHttpClientHandlerType>
<AndroidTlsProvider>btls</AndroidTlsProvider>
```

Note: If doing this manually in the `.csproj`, you need to add them to the debug AND release PropertyGroup.

Or programmatically set the HttpClient to use it:

```
client = new HttpClient(new AndroidClientHandler());
```

**Note**: You should be looking at the `InnerException` for these types of errors

```
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine(@"     Error {0}", ex.Message);
    Console.WriteLine(@"     Error {0}", ex.InnerException?.Message);
}
```

Comment: Can you tell me where i can find this option in Visual Studio? I can't set it programmaticaly because it's not working on UWP then.

Comment: @ChrisB Xamarin.Android **project settings**, goto Build / Android Build / General and use the AndroidClientHandler.

Comment: Will mention that for me, changing ONLY the second parameter worked (TLS1.2), changing the httpclient implementation also would cause issues.