# Xamarin: Android app does not load Https images

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm developing a Multiplatform application in Xamarin and I can not load https images from an api on android. If I run a build in Windows Phone, how images are loaded in Android does not, so I ask, how to fix?

Sorry for english, use google translate

**Android - Print - No Image**

[image]

**UWP**
[image]

https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/274026/xamarin-app-android-n%C3%A3o-carrega-imagens-https

Code Home.cs

```
 namespace AppNewsPlay.Views
{

    public partial class Home : TabbedPage
    {
        //private UltimasNoticias UltimasNoticias;
        List<UltimasNoticias> UNoticias;

        public TabbedPage Detail { get; private set; }

        public Home()
        {


            UNoticias = new List<UltimasNoticias>();
            ObterUltimasNoticias();
            InitializeComponent();

        }

        private async void ObterUltimasNoticias()
        {

            //   var jsonRequest = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(UNoticias);
            // var httpContent = new StringContent(jsonRequest, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
            var resp = string.Empty;

            try
            {
                var uri = new HttpClient();
                uri.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://api.newsplay.com.br");
                var url = "/api/post/";
                var result = await uri.GetAsync(url);


                if (!result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    await DisplayAlert("Erro de Conexão", "Não foi possível obter as notícias do servidor, Tente novamente mais tarde!", "OK");
                    return;
                }

                resp = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();


            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                await DisplayAlert("Erro de Conexão com o Servidor", ex.Message, "OK");
                return;

            }

            // transformando o retorno em objeto através do json e deserealize e retornando em lista
            var UNoticias = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<UltimasNoticias>>(resp);

            //Adicionando os itens ao ListView na Home.xaml
            UnoticiasList.ItemsSource = UNoticias;

        }    

        private async void OnItemSelected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if(e.SelectedItem !=null)
            {
                var selection = e.SelectedItem as UltimasNoticias;
                //DisplayAlert("Você Selecionou", selection.Post_title, "ok");         

                await Navigation.PushAsync(new PostView());
                #region DisabledSelectionHighlighting
                ((ListView)sender).SelectedItem = null;
                #endregion
            }



        }


    }
}
```

Code Xaml

```
  <TabbedPage.Children>

    <ContentPage Title="Ultimas Notícias" Icon="">
        <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout
                    Spacing="20">      
                    <Label Text="Últimas Notícias"
                           FontSize="20"                        
                           FontAttributes="Bold"
                           VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
                           HorizontalOptions="Center"

                     />

            <ListView x:Name="UnoticiasList"
                              HasUnevenRows="True"      
                              SeparatorColor="White"
                              SeparatorVisibility="Default"
                              ItemSelected="OnItemSelected"
                              >


                        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <ViewCell>

                                        <StackLayout
                                             Padding="20"                                          

                                             Orientation="Vertical"
                                            >

                                            <Image Source="{Binding Guid}"
                                                                       WidthRequest="250"
                                                                       HeightRequest="150"
                                                                       VerticalOptions="Center"

                                                                        />


                                            <Label x:Name="Post_title" Text="{ Binding Post_title }"
                                                               FontSize="16"
                                                               FontAttributes="Bold"  

                                                               HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                                                               />

                                            <Label x:Name="Post_content" Text="{ Binding Post_content }"
                                                   FontSize="12"                                                
                                                   HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                                                   VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
                                                   HeightRequest="70"

                                                   />

                                            <Label x:Name="Post_ad" Text="{Binding Post_ad}"
                                                   FontSize="11"                                            
                                                   HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"   
                                                   />                                        

                                        </StackLayout>                                    

                                </ViewCell>
                            </DataTemplate>                            
                        </ListView.ItemTemplate>                    
                    </ListView>
                </StackLayout>
        </ContentPage.Content>
    </ContentPage>


    <ContentPage Title="Xbox" Icon="">
        <ContentPage.Content>
        </ContentPage.Content>

    </ContentPage>

    <ContentPage Title="Playstation" Icon="">
        <ContentPage.Content>

        </ContentPage.Content>
    </ContentPage>

</TabbedPage.Children>
```

Return Json Api  image Https:

[image]

Comment: @SushiHangover does not give error simply does not load the image in android, windows phone loads

Comment: 1) You question is not detailed enough for anyone to answer directly 2) Show the code that you are using 3) Are your http requests secure (SSL/HTTPS based?) 4) If so what SSL protocol does your server support? 5) Are you using the `AndroidClientHandler`? i.e. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48475378/httpclient-not-working-on-android/48475612#48475612 6) There will be errors, either posted to `logcat` and/or direct Exception / InnerException (make sure that you are not catching and ignoring them

Comment: @SushiHangover  not able to publish the code here stackoverflow does not leave, says that the code is large, 
in the link that I posted has the code that I published in a forum in brazil next to the images

Comment: @SushiHangover 
in regards to your queries, to get the data use httpclient, and the server has certificate, it is hosted on the hostgator, but I do not know to inform these details that you asked me. 
the httpclient returns the data up to a url but the android only displays text in the view

Comment: I managed to publish the code

Comment: I followed the steps of the link and added the AndroidClientHandler but even then the app does not show the images

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem as follows:

I noticed that when displaying an image, the hosting server creates a redirect before.

Al to get around the problem, I accessed my api and changed the return adding the address before, as the image below, done that the app started to display the images on Android

[image]